# How to prevent type information being lost during Serialization of GeoDjango objects?

Tags: json, django, geodjango

In my Django app, I have the following dictionary:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
>>> myDict = {"A": 1, "B": "Z", "C": Point(70.0, 30.0,),}
```

I need to serialize this object and return it from an API. I do it like this:

```
>>> from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
>>> class GeoJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
...     def default(self, obj):
...         if isinstance(obj, Point):
...             return obj.coords
...         return super(GeoJSONEncoder, self).default(obj)

>>> from django.utils import simplejson
>>> json.dumps(simplejson.dumps(myDict, cls=GeoJSONEncoder))
'"{\\"A\\": 1, \\"B\\": \\"Z\\", \\"C\\": [70.0, 30.0]}"'
```

I have another API that takes this same serialized data from the client and seeks to insert it into an instance of one of my models:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class MyModel(models.Model):
    A = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False,)
    B = models.CharField(max_length=254,null=False, blank=False,)
    C = models.PointField(null=False, blank=False, srid=4326)


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ["A", "B", "C",]

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        assert instance is None
        logger.info("attrs = %s" % attrs)
        myInstance = MyModel(**attrs)
        return myInstance
```

When I run the curl command

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"A": 1, "B": "Z", "C":[-77.260768, 39.113707]}' http://localhost:9876/apiEndPoint/
```

I see the following log message:

```
[2014-09-01 03:50:41] INFO attrs = {'A': 1, 'C': [-77.260768, 39.113707], 'B': u'Z'}
```

But then it produces the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot set MyModel GeometryProxy with value of type: <type 'list'>
```

Is there some way I can make the deserialization automatically work correctly for an object which I myself have serialized? Can the serialization somehow preserve the information that this was a PointField, not a list?

I can of course manually fill in the fields the the PointField "C" in the `restore_object` method. But I just think there must be a better way.

Comment: can you add the code of the view that handle this url: http://localhost:9876/apiEndPoint/??? Without it, it's difficult to know what is wrong with your code. Nevertheless, i see some odd things: 1) why are you doing two consecutives json dumps? (json.dumps(simplejson.dumps(myDict, cls=GeoJSONEncoder))) 2) when you want to deserialize, you should use simplejson.loads or json.loads (these are the opposite of dumps)

Comment: Have you tried changing the `List` to a Dict or Tuple?